# Place radiobuttons on jQuery ui tab navigation panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to place [**this**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) kind of radiobutton on tabs navigation panel. Something like that:

```
________________________________________________________
|tab1|tab2|tab3|               |button1|button2|button3|
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
            <div id="tabs">                               <ul>                                          
                    <li><a href="#tab1"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2"><span>tab2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3"><span>tab3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" checked="checked"/><label for="radio1">button1</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">button2</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">button3</label>
               </div>

            <div id="tab1"></div>
            <div id="tab2"></div>
            <div id="tab3"></div>   
</div>
```

what is the better way of doing this?

Or should i use absolute positioning for radiobutton to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

When i wrapped  tabs into div and  `float:left` on that and `float:right` on radio it didn't work

```
<div id="tabs">
<div style="float:left" >     

                        <ul><li><a href="#tab1"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2"><span>tab2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3"><span>tab3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
</div>
                    <div id="radio" style="float:right">
                        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" checked="checked"/><label for="radio1">button1</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">button2</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">button3</label>
                </div>

                <div id="tab1"></div>
                <div id="tab2"></div>
                <div id="tab3"></div>   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning is not needed in your example. Just use `float: left` and `float: right` on two `div`'s.